# Run multiple websites on a single Ubuntu Server 15.10 using Apache2

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I am using Ubuntu Server 15.10

I am referring [run-multiple-websites-single-ubuntu-server-using-apache2](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/09/run-multiple-websites-single-ubuntu-server-using-apache2/) blog.

Issues

1. It seems my apache2 directory is now `/var/www/html/` so couldn't follow the above document properly

My Virtual Hosts

1. Default Server
   `Address Any`
   `Port Any   Server Name Automatic`
   `Document Root Automatic`
2. Virtual Server
   `Address website1.com`
   `Port 80    Server Name Automatic`
   `Document Root /var/www/html/website1.com`
3. Virtual Server
   `Address website2.com`
   `Port 80    Server Name Automatic`
   `Document Root /var/www/html/website2.com`

But when i try to access my `website1.com` it goes to the correct virtual host but my `website2.com` is just redirecting to `website1.com`.

Also
`vi /var/www/html/index.php`
`require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/website1.com/wp-blog-header.php' );`

It seems it's just pointing to `website1.com`. If i remove above line then none of the website work. so maybe my both virtual hosts are not working.

Could it be my `1. Default Server Virtual Hosts` just overtaking this.

Please help

```
***Content of conf files from /etc/apache2/sites-enabled***  <br/>
vi 000-default.conf   <br/>
```

Empty now, I went to `webmin` and i was seeing double entry of `website1.com` so i deleted the extra one and now i only have as shown below.

```
// added this just now after the first comment and enabled it  <br/>
vi website1.com.conf
<VirtualHost website1.com:80>  <br/>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost  <br/>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website1.com  <br/>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log  <br/>
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined  <br/>
</VirtualHost>  <br/>

vi webiste2.com.conf
<VirtualHost website2.com:80>  <br/>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost  <br/>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website2.com  <br/>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log  <br/>
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined  <br/>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [Paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com) of your current `.conf` files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` directory so that I can see what may be happening?

Comment: updated the question and added the content as requested by youI am struggling with how to add this conf content in new lines it just adds them in a single line

Comment: You can copy the entire file with `cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/file.conf | xclip -selection c` and then paste the entire output into a Paste file [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com). Then, you can edit your question with the link that you get from that Paste.

Comment: updated the question so my 000-default.conf  is pointing to website1.com could this be the issue

Comment: The `ServerName` directive seems to be missing from each virtual host. I've pasted what a complete `.conf` should look like in my answer.

Comment: While not off topic on AU, this question may be better suited for [SF].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically sites on Apache are handled through `*.conf` files in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory. Here is an example from my server, which is hosting [www.brownvpn.tk](http://www.brownvpn.tk), [www.browntech.tk](http://www.browntech.tk), [www.techyteen.tk](http://www.techyteen.tk), and a couple of others.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName browntech.tk
        ServerAdmin your@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tech
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The comments are very helpful. Each file needs to be pretty much the same as this. However, you may want to remove the `Rewrite` lines if you don't have SSL enabled or you want to allow HTTP as well as HTTPS traffic. We see up at the top the two most important lines. **ServerName** and **DocumentRoot**. The **ServerName** field should be the domain that points to that **DocumentRoot** path. So, you will need two configuration files(four if you want www.domain1.com as well as domain1.com).

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
touch site1.conf
touch site2.conf
```

Then, in your preferred editor, copy and paste my example configuration file, making the two edits (three if you count setting it to your email, four if you take out those rewrite lines) into each of `site1.conf` and `site2.conf`.

```
sudo a2ensite site1 site2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That will enable the two sites and redirect the URLs accordingly.

Comment: Fixed my conf files as recommended, still having issue

Comment: my vi /var/www/html/index.php says require( dirname( FILE ) . '/website1.com/wp-blog-header.php' ); so if i remove /webiste1.com from it then none of the websites are working

Comment: i removed my index.php file and reverted back to out of box index.html file so now both website1.com and website2.com are pointing to just out of box apache page. It seems virtual hosts are not even doing anything

Comment: can you please share your 000-default.conf

Comment: Same exact thing except server name is brownvpn.tk

Comment: What are your two sites?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.unixmen.com/setup-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-15-10/

Finally these instructions worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already changed the `A` record of the domain to your server's IP address.
Now, let's say you have two websites **exampleone.in** and **exampletwo.in**. And the default website is **exampleone.in**. So, the default host path to **exampleone.in** would be **/var/www/html**. Then in order to host **exampletwo.in** create a folder named **exampletwo.in** inside **/var/www/** or opposite to **html** folder.

So, now you have two folders named as **html** and **exampletwo.in** inside **/var/www**.

Apache handles websites through **.conf** file inside **/etc/apache2/sites-available/**. So, fire-up your terminal and enter the following commands. Use `sudo` if required

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
touch exampletwo.conf
```

Now, open your favourite editor or use nano to change the content of **exampletwo.conf** to -

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.exampletwo.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/exampletwo.in

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

After creating a new **.conf** file, we will enable the new website.

```
sudo a2ensite exampletwo.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Viola, you have hosted the other site in the same ubuntu serve.